# serving the build from webpack giving 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8765,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [...],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

And here is my package.json to create and serve the build

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production --env file=production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode development --env file=development",
    "build:start": "cd dist && PORT=8765 npx serve",
    "start": "webpack serve --open --mode development --env file=development",
    "start:live": "webpack serve --open --mode development --live-reload --hot"
  },
```

The steps I am following to create and serve the build

1. yarn build
2. yarn build:start

It is opening the first page that is on `http://localhost:8765/` but the other paths are giving

```
404: The requested path could not be found
```

[image]

when hitting directly from the url.
What could be the issue here?

RouteProvider

```
const RouteProvider = () => {
    return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/user-login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/user" element={<User/>} />
            </Routes>
    );
}

export default RouteProvider;
```

App.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import RouteProvider from "./RouteProvider";
    
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Suspense fallback="loading">
        <RouteProvider />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

Comment: Did you use `BrowserRouter` or `HashRouter`? Does it work if remove the `ModuleFederationPlugin`? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, remove all unrelated code

Comment: Yes I am using `BrowserRouter`. Removing `ModuleFederationPlugin` did not make any difference. Please check the edited question